# Unable to get Resource Layout files while preparing jar library in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Android Jar Library (say it Library), within which I have several Activities. I have another Project (say ConsumerProject), where I have included above jar library. I need to use the Activities created in Library into ConsumerProject.

But my concern is that Jar file prepared by Gradle in Android Studio doesn't prepare files other than Java class files. I am unable to get Drawables, XML Layouts, etc.

Is it so that only Java files are packaged within Jar, or is there some way I am missing to get my Resource folder completely in it.

> After having answer I have added arr into my libs folder, edited the gradle as shown in image. Can you see what is the trouble here
>   [See this Image for Dependency Issue within my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpLHj.png)

Comment: yes res also can be export in jar , with res it would not integrate preoperly

Comment: Is there anything to be done specifically, since by default just java class files corresponding to Activities are only ported within Jar @MyMasterPeice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using android-gradle,so you can set your Library as an Library Project,after building it,you will get an **aar** product,then your consumerproject can add dependency for the aar.

Import your aar,follow this:File->new->module->Import Jar/aar package->select your aar,name it as **library(you can custom it)**,then and this code to your dependency:

```
compile project(':library')
```

then sync project,rebuild the project,it will be ok.

Comment: Yes, I willingly accept your opinion. 
But while importing .aar in ConsumerProject, it says Local Dependency only can be resolved via .Jar file. Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: Warning:Project app: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle:  ....\libs\app-debug.aar

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'. > Dependency Error

Comment: Please post your dependency code,otherwise I can't know why the problem existed.

Comment: I have added screenshot of my project Structure, along with the dependency prompt - http://i.stack.imgur.com/HpLHj.png

Comment: You shouldn't add aar to libs as file dependency,please see my updated answer.